# Seedling tray flies (fungus gnats)

Tags: seeds, seedlings

My seedlings trays (special the cultures that need quite some water) are infested with small flies (and larvae). I grow my seedling trays indoor.
Are they harmful for my cultures? How can I get rid of them in a natural way?

Thanks in advance

Comment: They are probably fungus gnats. Try searching this website for "fungus gnats", I have seen many posts about how to get rid of them. My personal favorite way is using nematodes...

Comment: Nematodes seems to be the more natural way indeed. I will explore that option if the problem comes around again.
Cause I need to react fast, I'm currently using some 'bio' pesticide with hazard level EUH401 and water traps, which I'm not really sure if it is the right way to go.